# Добавление нового пользователя в GitLab

Tags: linux, postfix, git, gitlab, сервер

Поставил GitLab согласно инструкции https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md. Не обошлось без косяков, но в итоге всё работает. Возник вопрос - обязательно ли настраивать почтовый сервер/клиент или можно как-то добавлять новых пользователей без подтверждения по email. Может можно просто отключить требование подтверждения или же добавлять пользователей ручками в базу? Подскажите. Или конфигурировать почтовый сервер обязательное требование?

Comment: > Может можно просто отключить требование подтверждения или же добавлять пользователей ручками в базу?

Думаю, что да, но потребуется расковырять, что за хэш там используется.

Вообще можно попробовать указать в качестве мыла user@host и ловить ссылку в своем ящике прямо на серваке.

upd. Вообще по умолчанию постфикс будет спокойно висеть и слать все куда надо, проблемы могут быть только из-за отсутствия dns-записей. Ну и никто не мешает указать в качестве провайдера smtp и какой-нибудь ящик на гугле.

Comment: Как раз следуя этой http://elijahpaul.co.uk/using-an-smtp-server-with-gitlab/ инструкции настроил smtp релей через gmail. Но сам по себе вопрос пусть и отпадает, но место быть имеет. Вот только я не понял, это постфикс шлёт через релей теперь, или gitlab?)

Comment: gitlab напрямую к gmail должен обращаться

Comment: Все-таки стоит юзать mail-server, т.к. кроме писем о создании юзеров, там еще куча разных плюх, типа уведомлений о создании пулл-реквестов, задач, добавлении пользователя в проект, и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

В администрировании (/admin) на панели пользователей (/admin/users) вы можете подтверждать/блокировать аккаунт пользователя посредством Web-интерефейса (пользователь должен пройти предварительно процедуру регистрации).